# bash: Call a function from a while with arguments

Tags: bash

I have this working:

```
$ find . -name 'copy_*.txt' |while read i ; do echo $i; git mv $i ${i%.txt}.cob ;done
```

I whant to have the main body in a bash function:

```
$ my_mv () { echo $1; mv $1 ${1%.cob}.toto; }
```

To then call it with:

```
$ find . -name 'copy_*.txt' |while read i ;do my_mv $i; done
```

But I get a silent execution and nothing append:

```
$ my_mv () { echo $1; mv $1 ${1%.cob}.toto; }
$ find . -name 'copy_*.txt' |while read i ;do my_mv $i; done
$
```

same with:

```
$ my_mv () { printf '%s\n' $1; mv $1 ${1%.cob}.toto; }
```

Comment: What is the result of `find . -name 'copy_*.txt'`? It it is empty, then an empty output is correct.  btw, quote `"$i"`and `"${i%.txt}.cob"`, otherwise you script is broken if `find` finds some files with spaces.

Comment: `export -f my_mv`  then use it in your function

Comment: It may not be related, but you're using `find` to find files with ".txt" extensions, but in the function you're trying to trim a ".cob" extension.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : In this case, a renaming of the file would still occur, just to a different name than the OP expected, for instance `x.txt` would become `x.txt.toto`.

Comment: @user3313834 : You don't output anything, so no wonder it is silent. Use `mv -v` to see what's going on. Aside from this, I wonder why you pipe the output of your `find` into a `while`, instead of simply using the `-exec` option of `find`.

Comment: I output `echo $i` or `printf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's not working, because you're searching for files `copy_*.txt` and are trying to move files with suffix `.cob`. Furthermore
your variables are not quoted and will cause problems with white space in filenames.

Export your function to make `my_mv` available in `find` and use `-exec` to prevent problems with filenames containing newlines:

```
my_mv () { for i; do echo "$i"; mv "$i" "${i%.cob}.toto"; done; } 
export -f my_mv
find . -name 'copy_*.cob' -exec bash -c 'my_mv "$@"' bash {} +
```

---

Its often easier to use a small shell script instead of a function:

```
find . -name 'copy_*.cob' -exec sh -c '
  for i; do
    echo "$i"
    mv "$i" "${i%.cob}.toto"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Or move the code into a shell script `mymv.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

for i; do
  echo "$i"
  mv "$i" "${i%.cob}.toto"
done
```

and execute the script in `find`:

```
find . -name 'copy_*.cob' -exec ./mymv.sh {} +
```